# C++ 3D Angular Velocity

Tags: c++, velocity

I'm having a little trouble with my game. I'm trying to get a ball to move from one point to another. Heres my code:

```
void Create()
{
    // Initialise points
    StartPosition - { 20, 0, 5 };
    EndPosition = { -20, 0, 5 };
}

void Calculate()
{
    // Calculate difference in axis
    float X = EndPosition.x - StartPosition.x;
    float Z = EndPosition.z - StartPosition.z;

    // Calculate y-axis rotation
    float Rotation = atan2(Z, X) * (180 / M_PI); 

    // Calculate velocity
    Velocity.x = cos( Rotation ) * 5;
    Velocity.y = 0.0f;
    Velocity.z = sin( Rotation ) * 5;
}
```

I know that the rotation is being calculated correctly (180), however it calculates the velocities wrong:

```
X: -2.9923
Y: 0
Z: -4.00576
```

Now seeing as both the start and end points are Z = 5, I would think the Z axis velocity should be 0?

Have I completely missed something?

Comment: If you want to make your ball bounce from one point to the next, don't use rotations. The trajectory of a bouncing ball is a parabola, which is incidently much easier to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are calling the standard C/C++ `cos` and `sin` functions, they accept radians, not degrees. Remove the `* (180 / M_PI)` and you should see the expected result.

Comment: Thanks. Should I be concerned that the Z velocity is now displaying at -4.37114e-007

Answer (score 1):

I can see the following potential problems here

1. You are converting the output of `atan2` to degrees and using degrees in `cos` and `sin` which take radians.
2. The exact rotation you are attempting is not well explained in terms of the axis of rotation. I assume `mRotation` should be `Rotation`. Anyway, it is not clear which rotation matrix applies so I cannot tell what your `Velocity.X/Z` should be.

Comment: Sorry, am currently calculating Y axis rotation as the two points will remain on the same Y axis value.